# Is it possible to set a symbolic breakpoint for when an iOS device turns to landscape?

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

I'm debugging an issue where the device unexpectedly turns to landscape and back to portrait orientation, and trying to find the root cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use either of these in `lldb`:

```
b -[UIDevice setOrientation:animated:]
b -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]
```

That's Apple private API so no guarantees for future iOS versions, but upon landscape/portrait rotation I do hit a breakpoint on:

- iOS12.4.1
- iOS15.1
- iOS16.1